# Highest diff between max and min values in a pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this df:

```py
values = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[1,2,5,9], 'c':[10,1000,20,30]}
d=pd.DataFrame(values)
```

What's the best way to get the column with the highest spread between max and min values?

The output shoub be: `c` because `1000 - 10` > `9 - 1` > `4 - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple way:

```
d.apply(lambda x: max(x)-min(x)).idxmax()
```

Output:

```
c
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of doing that is as follows

`(d.max() - d.min()).idxmax()`

Comment: This is more efficient than the chosen answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d.columns[np.argmax(np.ptp(d, axis=0))]
```

Output:

```
'c'
```